# Check if argument exist in ColdFusion

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I have a question about arguments that are passed with ajax in coldfusion. So I have three arguments that I'm passing date1, date2 and meetingDate. I have to compare three of these arguments and return the string based on the dates. Here is my logic:

```
<cfset sigDate1 = dateFormat(trim(arguments.date1),'yyyy/mm/dd')>
<cfset sigDate2 = dateFormat(trim(arguments.date2),'yyyy/mm/dd')>
<cfset meetDate = dateFormat(URLDecode(arguments.meetingDate),'yyyy/mm/dd')>

<cfelseif (sigDate1 LT meetDate) OR (sigDate2 LT meetDate)>
    <cfset myResult = "blockDate">
<cfelse>
```

My current code has one problem, if I just pass one of these two dates(date1 or date2) I will always get "blockDate" returned with my ajax function. I detected the problem and if I just pass date1 but not date2 my elseif still will be executed no matter what. So I was trying to fix this problem with using one extra cfif and check if my date1 and date2 isDefined but that did not fix the problem. If anyone have any idea how to fix this bugg please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a CFIF.

Comment: Make the arguments mandatory or give them default values, whichever satisfies your business requirements.

Comment: ... Also despite the question title, the code posted uses all three (3) arguments as if they *always* exist. Are you actually omitting arguments when the function is called, ie `yourFunctionName( date1, meetingDate)` OR simply passing in an empty value `yourFunctionName( date1, "", meetingDate)` ?

Comment: I'm always passing the argument no matter what. That's what cause my code to crash. So I was wondering what is the best way to prevent empty string to be compared with the date value?

Comment: Specify `type="date"` in your cfargument tag.

Comment: That explains it. Passing anything, even an empty string, means the argument *is* defined. So both IsDefined and StructKeyExists (preferred) will return `true`. If the function requires dates, the simplest option is to use `type=date` instead and omit any optional arguments entirely. Then you can use `structKeyExists()` to verify if the arguments are present.  Technically you also use type=string, but in terms of validation you have to DIY inside the cffunction.  Either way, keep in mind CF's interpretation of dates (especially functions like `IsDate`) is *very* liberal ...

Comment: @DanBracuk - Most likely they need to change how they are calling the function as well. `type=date` does not accept invalid values, like an empty strings.

Comment: @Leigh, that's what I see as the purpose of the type attribute.

Comment: @DanBracuk - For type checking sure, but a lot of people think they can still pass in placeholders, like the OP is doing, and that the function will still work. It won't. Not unless it receives valid dates.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different ways to handle this. As I understand it; the arguments always exist, but you are concerned they may have blank values.

Here are some ideas you should be able to adapt to get you started:
    use defaults

```
<cfset sigDate1 = iif(isDate(trim(arguments.date1),'dateFormat(trim(arguments.date1),'yyyy/mm/dd')','[default value]')/>
<cfset sigDate2 = iif(isDate(trim(arguments.date2),'dateFormat(trim(arguments.date2),'yyyy/mm/dd')','[default value]')/>
<cfset meetDate = iif(isDate(trim(URLDecode(arguments.meetingDate),'dateFormat(trim(URLDecode(arguments.meetingDate),'yyyy/mm/dd')','[default value]')/>

or (test dates)

<cfif isDate(trim(arguments.date1)) and isDate(trim(arguments.date2)) and isDate(URLDecode(arguments.meetingDate))>
    <cfset sigDate1 = dateFormat(trim(arguments.date1),'yyyy/mm/dd')/>
    <cfset sigDate2 = dateFormat(trim(arguments.date2),'yyyy/mm/dd')/>
    <cfset meetDate = dateFormat(URLDecode(arguments.meetingDate),'yyyy/mm/dd')/>
<cfelse>
    <--- error code --->
</cfif>

or (use try block)

<cftry>
    <cfset sigDate1 = dateFormat(trim(arguments.date1),'yyyy/mm/dd')/>
    <cfset sigDate2 = dateFormat(trim(arguments.date2),'yyyy/mm/dd')/>
    <cfset meetDate = dateFormat(URLDecode(arguments.meetingDate),'yyyy/mm/dd')/>
    <cfcatch type="expression">
        <--- error code --->
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```